Static variable and type: could there be another simpler way to implement a function that returns the same ID for each user-defined type?
I was working on creating an entity-component system on my own, and in doing this I have gotten help from a lot of YouTube videos, C++ references, recommended books, etc. While I was implementing a functionality that returns IDs for specific components(which are implements as structs), I started wondering:

How does this double-static thing work?

Would there be a better, simpler way to do this?


For question #1, I am certain that without using static twice, I cannot get the function I want, based upon the experimental code below:
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

struct Physics_c {};
struct Render_c {};
struct Collision_c {};

using componentID = std::size_t;

const inline componentID getID() noexcept {
    static componentID lastID = 0;
    return lastID++;
}

template <typename T>
const inline componentID gettypeID() noexcept{
    std::cout << "function called for " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    componentID typeID = getID();
    return typeID;
}

template <typename T>
const inline componentID getCompID() noexcept{
    std::cout << "function called for " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    static componentID typeID = getID();
    return typeID;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << gettypeID<Physics_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << gettypeID<Physics_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << gettypeID<Physics_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << gettypeID<Render_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << gettypeID<Render_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << gettypeID<Render_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << gettypeID<Collision_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << gettypeID<Collision_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << gettypeID<Collision_c>() << "\n";

    std::cout << getCompID<Physics_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << getCompID<Physics_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << getCompID<Physics_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << getCompID<Render_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << getCompID<Render_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << getCompID<Render_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << getCompID<Collision_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << getCompID<Collision_c>() << "\n";
    std::cout << getCompID<Collision_c>() << "\n";

    return 0;
}

Here are the results:
function called for 9Physics_c
0
function called for 9Physics_c
1
function called for 9Physics_c
2
function called for 8Render_c
3
function called for 8Render_c
4
function called for 8Render_c
5
function called for 11Collision_c
6
function called for 11Collision_c
7
function called for 11Collision_c
8
function called for 9Physics_c
9
function called for 9Physics_c
9
function called for 9Physics_c
9
function called for 8Render_c
10
function called for 8Render_c
10
function called for 8Render_c
10
function called for 11Collision_c
11
function called for 11Collision_c
11
function called for 11Collision_c
11

I don't get why the value for the static side of typeID doesn't change, even if both gettypeID and getCompID get called for every function call. I thought I knew the basics about the static keyword, but this thing has been killing me... Is it like although the code within the template function is executed, the previous result of the other static function is just returned or what? Is the other (inline) function is told not to run more than once by the compiler?
For question #2, I tried to create a vector that contains each typeID, but I think it isn't any simpler than the previous code, and it is a waste of memory to make another container just to get a proper typeID. Furthermore, I have to manually input all the possible component types to the component ID vector just for the sake of getting a number for each component. Not to mention the code itself is uglier than before...
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Physics_c{};
struct Render_c{};

static std::vector<std::type_index> componentVec {};

template <typename T>
void createCompVec () {
    componentVec.push_back(typeid(T));
}
int main() {
    createCompVec<Physics_c>();
    createCompVec<Render_c>();
    for (auto p : componentVec) {
        std::cout << p.name() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

Would there be a more efficient way to achieve what I want to do?

please focus on one specific question. Why do you think you need something "more efficient" ? I cant imagine something that is more efficient or simpler than just returning a value.

for questions about the output of the code please include the output and the expected output in the question

A static local variable gets initialized the first time the function is called, and then keeps its value between calls. Is the problem perhaps that two of the functions hold static ids, while one does not?

componentID typeID = getID(); is not static. It retrieves a new value from getID every time gettypeID is called. And getID returns a value that increments on each call. What else is unclear?

Here is the same principle using globals rather than static locals for state storage. Note that each global variable is initialized exactly once.

@BoP I know where the difference is, but am not sure exactly about how this works.  Is the result of a function call by a certain type stored within the static variable declared in the function scope? How does this work? was the first question. I know this would be a silly question for all who are fluent in C++, but I just want a kind explanation for this.

the static keyword has differnt meanings. I think we were all a bit mislead by you writing "I thought I knew the basics about the static keyword" because what you observe is nothing but how function local static variables are supposed to work (and perhaps you read about one of the different uses of the static keyword)

or maybe I am wrong. It would help to clarify if you say what else you expected static to mean here

With a static local variable, the initialization of that variable is special.  Magical even.
static Type x = some_code();

This is converted by the C++ compiler into a "global" variable x.  When this line of code is first reached, a thread-safe atomic guard is used to initialize x and call some_code().  Other threads will wait for the first one to reach it to complete.  (If some_code() reaches this line recursively, bad things (tm) happen).
some_code() is only run once.
Then the global variable x is put into a list of things to destroy when the program shuts down.
Without the static, some_code() would be run every time we reached this line.
static auto id = get_next_id();

vs
auto id = get_next_id();

in the first case, get_next_id() is called once per execution of the entire program, and in the second, get_next_id() is called once per invocation of the function.
Now, the next bit is because it is a template.  Template functions are not functions; they are templates to create functions.
template <typename T>
const inline componentID getCompID() noexcept{
  std::cout << "function called for " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
  static componentID typeID = getID();
  return typeID;
}

for each type T. getCompID<T> is a different function.  So each of them get a distinct "magic static" typeID global variable.  So getID is called once per type T.
For efficiency, your compiler will generate a distinct getCompID() function for each type that is used in your program.  A solution involving an unordered_map< some_type_info, int > (or other container) could use less program memory (like, in the exe) and more RAM; you might care about that?  "efficiency" is a vague word, you'd have to be more specific about what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Wow, your answer helped me a lot, thanks! For the efficiency thing, I wasn't actually referring to the memory usage, but much more in a common sense; simpler, or shorter. It was my bad, I think. I had to be much clearer in my question. Thanks again for your answer!

#1
Each instantiation of a function template gets its own copy of a function local static variable. Function local static variables are initialized exactly once.
Hence when you do
 int get_id() {
      static int id= 0;
      return id++;
 }

calling get_id many time increments id on every call.
And here
  template <typename T> 
  int get_type_id() {
        static int id = get_id();
        return id;
  }

The static variable id is initialized once for each instantiation of the template. Calling get_type_id<Foo> will always return the same value, and get_type_id<Bar> will return a different id, but also always the same.
Hence if you call
 std::cout << get_type_id<int>();       // calls get_id
 std::cout << get_type_id<int>();       // does not call get_id
 std::cout << get_type_id<int>();       // also not
 std::cout << get_type_id<double>();    // calls get_id
 std::cout << get_type_id<double>();    // does not call get_id

expected output is
 00011

If you remove the static in the template and write
  template <typename T> 
  int get_type_id_X() {
        int id = get_id();
        return id;
  }

Then it does not really matter anymore that it is a template, because every call of any instantiation of this function template will call get_id and return a different id on each call.
#2
If you want to get a unique id for each type, the code you have does that already. There is no reason to look for something more efficient, because merely returning a value is as efficient as it can get.

Thank you for your answer! I hadn't think of it in terms of the instantiation of the static variable. It helped a lot
